# Bluetooth volume defaults to maximum on each new connection

Tags: bluetooth

Every time I connect a Bluetooth headphone to my android phone the (Bluetooth) volume changes to max volume.

It doesn't matter what was the level of the normal volume (non-Bluetooth volume).

Example:
Listening on the phone speaker at 50% volume, I connect the Bluetooth headphone and once the connection is established the volume jumps to 100%.

How can I change that behavior?

It wasn't happening before with similar audio devices and now it happens with all/some devices.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is like a bug or a corner case.

Once it starts happening there is no CLEAR FIX.

Here I describe the path I took that lead me to resolve the issue.

**Test** after every change until resolved.

**Repeat** these steps (or variations of them) until resolved.

```
Connect bluetooth audio device
    Disable absolute volume option in Developer Options
Disconnect  bluetooth audio device
Connect bluetooth audio device
    Enable absolute volume option in Developer Options
Disconnect  bluetooth audio device
Connect bluetooth audio device
Disconnect  bluetooth audio device
    Disable absolute volume option in Developer Options
Connect bluetooth audio device
Disconnect  bluetooth audio device
    Enable absolute volume option in Developer Options
Connect bluetooth audio device
Disconnect  bluetooth audio device
```

Once resolved, you may want to do this once more to protect your ears.

```
Enable absolute volume option in Developer Options
```

The easier way to find the setting is to search for **volume**

[image]

And here is the specific setting

[image]